# Hide file from tacking area in Git

Tags: git, gitignore

I cannot hide special files from git status command

For example, I don't want to have phpstorm.php in my project and I added it to gitignore

But when I use git status command, That shows the message as follow:

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
phpstorm.php

Actually, I want to have phpstorm.php but hide from git status

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the file? Is it named `.gitignore`? Is it at the same directory level as `phpstorm.php`? higher? lower down?

Comment: @phd I'm sorry for my bad explanation, I want to only untacking phpstorm.php file

Comment: When I asked "*Can we see the file?*" I meant `.gitignore`. Did you name it name it `.gitignore` or `gitignore`?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add it to gitignore, Thank you @phd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `/phpstorm.php` or `phpstorm.php` as a line in your `.gitignore` file.

`/phpstorm.php` matches the `phpstorm.php` file of the same folder with `.gitignore`.

`phpstorm.php` matches all that files, e.g. including `someFolder/phpstorm.php`.

See [gitignore Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more information.